# How can I convince my manager to allow me to take leave to be a prosecution witness in the USA?

Tags: united-states, manager, legal, leave

Per [this question](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/86387/how-literally-do-courts-in-usa-interpret-face-to-face-confrontation-right-of-def) I posted on Law Stack Exchange site, I will soon be a witness in a criminal trial of another in the United States, for which **I was also a victim**. **The crime being prosecuted is the same crime for which I was a victim.** The crime is assault and burglary and is being prosecuted under state (vs. federal) jurisdiction.

The state (i.e. prosecution) requested I testify and let me know I will be a significant witness for their case against the defendant. If I can’t testify, there is significant likelihood of jury acquittal or nolle prosequi. If the jury acquits, the [Fifth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) double jeopardy clause bars subsequent prosecution for the same crime.

I have important job commitments (meetings with internal clients, being on call, my own and team members evaluations being due) during the days defendant will be on trial. Our company is under a hiring freeze and new team members will not be approved. Backfilling my role during my time testifying in court will be difficult as I am in a lead role managing a team. **As a result, my manager is unwilling to allow me to take leave to attend court to testify.**

As the responses in the linked question states, a face-to-face cross examination by the defense counsel will be required and a prerecorded disposition under oath will be disallowed due to the defendant's Confrontation Clause rights under the [Sixth Amendment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sixth_Amendment_to_the_United_States_Constitution) of the US Constitution.

As I am a victim of crime, I have a strong interest in seeing that the defendant is convicted. My testimony as a witness present on scene is important. This will be the only trial if acquittal were to occur.

**What can I do to convince my manager to allow me to take leave to testify in court for prosecution?**

Comment: “If jury acquits, fifth amendment double jeopardy clause bars subsequent prosecution for the same crime.” - This applies to the crime they are being prosecuted for against the victim, but the crime against you, is obviously a separate charge. *As Mike suggests, if it’s important to you, take leave and be the witness.*

Comment: @Donald, you misunderstood as I am the victim in the same case. There is no separate case

Comment: I don’t understand how your company feels like they can stop you from participating in the case. I think it goes back to you’ll have to decide if your willing to simply participate and tell your boss to pound sand. An alternative is changing your work hours on the days your testifying

Comment: Not sure this is even an issue. Aren't you required by law to be there when called up as a witness by the court? In which case the company would have no legal way to deny you leave (and probably this'd have to be paid leave even, but that'd be jurisdiction dependent). Check with the court and/or the lawyer who's calling you up.

Comment: How could your boss possibly deny you leave, if you are called upon to be a witness in court? I'm not an expert in US law, and not a fan of absolute freedoms that guide them, but I would be *very* surprised if "called upon as a wittness by the state" would not be protected.

Comment: You should really check if you're legally obliged to testify, which as far as I know should usually be the case. It might be different here because you're also the victim, but even then you might be able to ask the prosecution to formally require you to testify so that you have an official document to show your employer. If you're legally required to testify that removes any element of choice, on your side and your employer's.

Comment: Unrelated to the question at hand, I wonder if this is really the kind of workplace you want to be a part of going forward?  Perhaps this should be a wake-up call for you to start seeking another position elsewhere at a company that treats their employees better.

Comment: Are witnesses not getting a court summon in the USA? A written document explaining when and where they have to show up.

Comment: OP, how much time will testifying take you away from work?

Comment: @user253751 yes and no. I mean the boss _can_ fire OP for almost any reason they feel like. But if they are so essential to the business it would be absolutely foolish to do so. Does the boss really want to get rid of a good employee forever just because they are going to be unavailable for a short time?

Comment: @Seth R, hopefully 2 - 3 days at most. Although could be more, as I was eye witness and only person in the home at time of unlawful entry

Comment: Did you investigate if your home country legally requires your employer to allow this leave?

Comment: @user253751 - I live in the United States.  What you claim is not exactly the fully complete story on employee rights.

Comment: @nvoigt The problem is probably that if it's in another state, that state won't issue a subpoena to compel someone in another state to testify because it doesn't have the capacity to enforce it, so as far as the employer is concerned the OP is taking time off for a voluntary purpose.  It would probably be different if the prosecution was in the same state, in that case they could issue a subpoena to testify for the OP's benefit.

Comment: Please tag this with the state, the responsibilities of your employer depend heavily on state law (e.g. in Virginia, they have to give you unpaid time off, they can't penalize you for it, and they can't force you to use vacation/sick time...and if they don't do that, it's a misdemeanor https://law.lis.virginia.gov/vacode/title18.2/chapter10/section18.2-465.1/ ). Probably _most_ states have some law about this since it is very much in the public interest that witnesses are able to testify.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian "Uniform Act to Secure the Attendance of Witnesses from without a State in Criminal Proceedings". All 50 states have enacted the Uniform Act law (per Google) so they certainly can compel you to show up even if you are in another state when they want you.

Comment: @IllusiveBrian That makes no sense. A subpoena is simply a piece of paper ordering you to show up (or produce documents). It's trivial to issue and is done by a defense or prosecuting attorney. Sometimes a witness may even request one, precisely as a work/school excuse. There is nothing to enforce in a subpoena by itself, you'd violate the subpoena then be subject to contempt of court or a bench warrant. That is the point at which the question of the cost and practicality of enforcement comes in. There's even a right to have a subpoena issued, both through discovery and confrontation clause

Comment: @user3067860 I didn't know that existed for criminal cases, if the state hasn't issued a subpoena the OP's attendance is still voluntary though.

Comment: Does your HR manual or employee handbook say anything about this situation ?

Comment: How much advance notice are we speaking (next week, or next year)? How much flexibility do you have with the commitments (rescheduling, remote attendance)?

Comment: I would be very interested to know whether your manager's manager, or your CEO for example,  agreed with your manager on this point. It might be worth asking about. There are loads of idiot managers around, but one person behaving unreasonably in your company doesn't mean that everyone else will too!

Comment: Please include your State.  Some states not only require that they allow you to go to court, but also require that they pay you for the time you miss, and forbid the company from counting that against your PTO.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I can’t testify, there is significant likelihood of jury acquittal or nolle prosequi. If the jury acquits, the Fifth Amendment double jeopardy clause bars subsequent prosecution for the same crime.

Yes, but if they [nolle prosequi](https://www.law.cornell.edu/wex/nolle_prosequi), then double jeopardy does not apply.  Which is why that is a likely result if the complaining witness is not available.  Because it does not bar a subsequent prosecution.  The bad part there is that the defendant might be let out of jail then, as there would be no active trial.  If the defendant is already out on bail, then that's less of an issue.

> meetings with internal clients, being on call, my own and team members evaluations being due

Of these three, I see only "meetings with internal clients" as being a serious issue for the one or two days that you are giving evidence.  And that seems a feasible block for not being able to attend meetings.  There should be some substitute for being on call during work hours.  Even if testifying, you should still be able to be on call outside of work (court) hours.  And evaluations are simply something that you will need to manage.  Again, spend time outside of normal work hours on them.

I would be surprised if scheduling conflicts were new to the prosecutors.  Ask the prosecutors what they want you to do.  Allow them to settle the case?  Answer a [subpoena](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/188640/125440)?  Call you as a witness first so as to have a predictable appearance time?  Reschedule the prosecution for after the holidays?  Do they want to call your manager (might be a good lead up to a subpoena or rescheduling your appearance)?  Would your manager or other coworkers have any relevant testimony (their presence could also be compelled via subpoena if so)?

You also might talk to Human Resources (HR).  What is the corporate policy on responding to a subpoena (assuming you are served)?

Also note that while a simple recorded video statement does not meet the confrontation clause, a session attended by the defense attorney could.  The defendant might need to be there as well, but the judge does not.  The most important part of the confrontation clause is the ability to cross examine.  If the defendant's presence is also required, that also seems easier to schedule than time before the judge.  It's dead easy if the defendant is in jail.

You might get better feedback on Law.SE if you ask them "Can a manager refuse an employee time off to testify in court?"  Also, you should specify the state of prosecution and (if it differs) the state where you are employed.  Also, is there a statute of limitations?  Are you running up against it?  I.e. is it prosecute now or not at all.

Your existing question asks if you can give a simple video statement, presumably without cross examination.  A response was that you need to submit to cross examination.  It is of course possible to submit to cross examination remotely.  That happens all the time in civil cases and with third party testimony.  Whether that is something that the court would allow in your case may be a different story.

Answer (score 200):

> What can I do to convince my manager to allow me to take leave to
> testify in court for prosecution?

Have the prosecution issue a [subpoena](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subpoena) for your testimony. That would legally compel your presence and (unpaid) leave.

In the unlikely case that your employer subsequently decided to fire you, you would have a great cause for an action for unfair dismissal.

Comment: "It's not my fault, I HAVE to be there boss, I really wanted to work but oh boi, they're gonna put me in jail if I don't show up and then I'm missing from work for even longer". Also: Since you're on the same side as the prosecution they should be pretty inclined to help you with that subponea

Comment: @Hobbamok Is there any chance the boss could go to jail? *That* would motivate them to accept the time away for the employee.

Comment: @AndrewMorton sadly, our (= pretty much any western legal) system is set up in such a way that employers screwing up at worst costs them a bit. Bar direct fraud or actively endangering lives, the boss will not go to jail in almost any circumstances

Comment: Crime: obstruction of justice (or even witness tampering)?  Not sure it would hold up through a conviction without some relationship between the boss and the defendant, but even an indictment without a conviction is annoying.

Comment: @Hobbamok - I wouldn't agree with the "pretty much any western legal", bosses going to gaol isn't that uncommon in Europe for fragrant and blatant breaches of the law.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - Employers would be in contempt of court most likely and continued refusal to give someone leave to appear in court would likely result in the arrest of the employer and them being dragged in to appear before the judge... But my comment wasn't aimed at this scenario explicitly, it was aimed at "employers screwing up at worst costs them a bit", which isn't true

Comment: @JoeStrazzere IANAL, this is not a legal advice, but I heard judges being very not happy when bosses try to prevent workers from jury duty. Judges have very broad powers with regards contempt of court and while I haven't heard anything regarding subpoena I read (as text on the Internet - so take it with grain of salt) that judges can send an officer of the court to make sure that retaliation doesn't happen. My understanding is that one does *not* want to go on the bad side of judge in relation to court proceeding...

Comment: @JoeStrazzere US and I was talking of course about jury summons and subpoena. Europe usually don't have juries and therefore no jury duties.

Comment: " you would have a great cause for an action for unfair dismissal." - really? I thought most states in the US had "at will" employment which means the boss can fire you at any time for no reason?

Comment: This is the best course of action

Comment: @komodosp They can fire you for no reason, but they can't fire you for a set of protected reasons (e.g. skin color, attending jury duty, etc.). It is notoriously difficult to show that you were actually fired for a protected reason vs. no reason, except that someone who's stupid enough to fire someone over things like that is also often stupid enough to put it into writing.

Answer (score 33):

> What can I do to convince my manager to allow me to take leave to testify in court for prosecution?

It's not your job to convince your manager of anything.  Treat this situation no different than if you woke up sick one day and could not make it to work.  You let your manager know that you are unable to make it and let them know the reason and you just don't show up.  Obviously, in this case you let your manager know well ahead of time and not the morning of your testimony.  If they require some sort of proof once you return ( e.g. a doctors note in the case that you are sick ), I am sure that you would have no trouble getting a letter from the prosecutor or some agent of the court if you don't already have one.

If the manager takes issue with your decision when you return, you escalate this through the proper channels at your company.  Also, I would seriously consider looking for a new company to work for if you actually have any issues with such a serious matter and the company is unwilling to accommodate you.

Comment: The difference from being sick is that you don't have control over whether  and when you're sick.

Comment: @Barmar Did OP have control over whether and when they were assaulted?  Does OP have control over the docket of a state court?

Comment: @Theodore The whole question is premised on the OP having a choice of whether to testify or not.

Comment: @Barmar OP can't choose to be summoned as a witness anymore than they can choose to be sick.  With either situation it is ultimately their decision to show up for work or not.  Plenty of sick employees show up to work anyway and pass it along to everyone else.  Any employer that values their employee so little that they would attempt to prevent an employee from acting as a witness in a trial is clearly not one worth working for

Comment: @sf02 If they don't have a choice, why do they need to "ask for permission"? You're ignoring the point of the question, which is that they believe they have a choice, and the employer is forcing the choice they don't want.

Comment: I fully agree with you that a manager like this is totally unreasonable.

Comment: This sounds like useful advice for future readers. The OP, unfortunately, already made the mistake of asking their manager (instead of just telling them).

Comment: @Barmar saying "you don't need permission" is a valid answer to "how do I ask permission?"

Comment: @SethR Sure, but don't say it's like sick leave.

Comment: The boss apparently also thinks they have a choice, since they said the OP couldn't take the time off.

Comment: Legally, you do have a choice unless you're subpoenaed.

Comment: @Barmar There's generally no law that says you can't show up to work sick. There are laws against not showing up to court, punishable by arrest and fines. Contempt of court may be treated as a misdemeanor or even felony conviction, with the consequent loss of voting rights, can't possess a gun, can't be licensed as a doctor, teacher or lawyer, etc. It is far more serious than showing up to work sick.

Comment: @user71659 There might be workplace safety laws, especially since the pandemic; but even if not, it's generally in the employer's benefit that infectious employees stay home. And some sicknesses simply make you incapable of working effectively. As for court, IANAL, but I don't think it's contempt unless you refuse a subpoena.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, so we have some options here:

For the sake of the answer, I'm going to assume that you are only going to be present for when you have to testify, rather than sit through the whole trial, in order to minimize how much time you are absent.

Option 1, the Direct Method: "Boss, I will not be coming in on these days. You can either approve a leave of absence or I will develop a nasty case of vomitting that lasted only 24-48 hours" - this will likely piss your boss off, but it does set a very clear expectation that you are not coming in.

Option 2, the 'I don't need the job, Nuclear Method': I can't think that any business would be looked upon favorably in the community if word got out that they weren't allowing a Victim of a Crime to testify in court, to get Justice against their victimizer. I'm sure there is some local news entity that has a sufficiently 'stick-it-to-the-man' leaning that would love to write a hit piece about a company that did this.

However, as per tag line - this is the Nuclear option.

Option 3, HR and Higher-ups (semi-Nuclear): You go above and around your boss, explain to HR and your Bosses boss that you need to take these specific days off for a Legal Matter, that you are a witness in a court case (they don't need to know you are the victim) and if you can get the Prosecuting attorney to write you a letter on a legal letterhead explaining you are pivotal to the case etc. - then see what they say.

Option 4, Alternate arrangements: So, if you can get a letter from the Prosecutor, this would help in this scenario - Depending on your job, you may be able to work outside your normal hours (as in, go to court during the Day, work as if you were at work on that night) so that the company still gets your 8 hours. If it's a job that requires a physical presence (like Shift work) ask if you can get put onto a different shift to allow you to attend court, whilst still making up time. If neither of these are applicable - try and find out if you can arrange things in such a manner where you minimize the impact - such as agreeing to work extra hours the week before trial so that you are ahead of the deadline.

Option 5 - Quit: I mean, it's fairly self-explanatory, but I would seriously question my continued employment with a Company that would deny leave for such a serious matter. Denying leave cause you want to go to the Bahamas for some Sun and Fun whilst things are crazy - sure - but things like Legal stuff, Medical Stuff and Child stuff (within reason) are hard boundaries for me - and I would start investigating alternate employment. And I can guarantee you, if they are up a certain creek at the moment with a hiring freeze and can't back-fill your role for a temporary absence, they are gonna struggle to back-fill your roll for a permanent absence.

Ultimately, you are gonna have to negotiate with your boss, I'd try and limit it to just the Days you are going to testify, I would be surprised if your testimony would last more than several days - and then try and find a solution with your boss where you minimize the impact to the business (which they are justifiable concerned about) in exchange for you going to trial.

Comment: *"Depending on your job, you may be able to work outside your normal hours (as in, go to court during the Day, work as if you were at work on that night) so that the company still gets your 8 hours."* I'm not familiar with US laws, but in some places this might be illegal because workers are required to have a at least Y hours of rest every X hours of work, and being called to court during your workday is definitely not rest.

Comment: Option 1 is probably the most reasonable, but the exact wording matters. Also, you probably don't need to "develop a nasty case of vomitting" (as a pretext for sick leave) if "being called to court" is already a good legal reason to get leave.

Comment: Check your company's policy. They may already have a provision for "personal business time" that covers taking leave for emergencies. You might have to take it as unpaid time, or there may be other limitations, but that would be the simplest way to go over your boss's head.

Comment: Option 1) would be a reason to be fired for cause where I live. Given that the US does not even *need* a reason, I cannot imagine that going over well with a boss that obviously is not reasonable.

Comment: I'm not an expert, but I'm pretty sure people have to be in court to be prepared to give testimony for much longer than the testimony actually takes.  They probably don't need to attend the entire trial, but at least in drama, they can be recalled to the stand, so there's probably a need for quite a bit of time off.

Comment: @stef there's no such limitation in US law.

Answer (score 5):

From your comment, testifying would mean missing work for 2-3 days, which is about the same amount of time (or less) you would likely be gone if you were to come down with a sudden illness. What would your boss do if that were to happen?

The nice thing here is that it won't be sudden. You know what days you will need to testify and can make a plan. Move your meetings, have coworkers cover your essential tasks for those days, then inform your boss that you won't be available those days. It's not a request, you have stuff to do outside of work. It happens. Just like if you were sick, they will figure out how to deal with your absence and the business will survive.

They would be absolutely foolish to penalize you for having obligations outside of work, especially if you proactively make a plan to minimize the impact of you being gone. If you feel like you need to extra leverage, follow Joe Strazzere's answer and request a subpeona so you are legally compelled to testify. Then just go and do your part to bring a dangerous criminal to justice.

Answer (score 3):

I feel your relationship with your boss may have already taken some damage, and not just for the obvious reason. **If you don't testify, and the defendant is acquitted, this might become a lifelong regret.** Aside from the seriousness of that, in your position I'm pretty sure I'd resent (and lose some respect for) my boss for putting commercial work commitments ahead of something that matters so much, both personally *and* to wider society.

I think suggestions to quit made by other answers are premature (and don't acknowledge the immense pressure that mortgages, medical coverage, family expectations and the fear of losing employment represent). Having said that, I think my attitude would be damaged, and it's unlikely I'd be able to stay in work there long term.

**You're damned if you do, and damned if you don't. So go with your conscience, and do the thing you'll least regret.** By which I mean, don't predicate your decision on whether you're successful in convincing your boss. Try by all means, but the decision must be yours, and not theirs.

The 'obvious' reason I alluded to at the start is that management is willing to damage their relationship with an important employee - you - due to *their* failings in management. No business should have *single points of failure* - individual systems or employees whose constant presence is essential to business operations. There always need to be backups. Knowledge, expertise and the ability to cover unexpected loss of personnel is something good management makes sure is taken care of. In this case, either your boss or their boss etc. is unwilling to invest in the necessary level of redundancy, and they are unwilling to take responsibility for that failure. They are making it your fault. If you were hit by a bus tomorrow, whose fault would it be that the clients were let down? Management's fault, for not having measures in place ahead of time. At the same time, clients are (usually) human, and I believe most of them would be understanding given a brief and honest explanation of your absence.

I would also argue that your boss(es) have not taken into account that damaging a relationship with a valuable employee has an actual cost to the business, and in the long term it might exceed the immediate cost of your absence.

(Edit: I forgot that you too are in management. So I'll leave it up to you to decide whether you could be better preparing your team to manage without leadership in an emergency. How realistic that is obviously depends on how long you've been working together, but perhaps you have time to start preparing them now for some of your job functions if you do go ahead with the trial. It also seems unlikely that timely member evaluations really *are* that important if you're already on a hiring freeze. It's not like you're going to replace any of them, so surely those evaluations can wait a week?)

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost: *Get a lawyer*.

You're way out of your depth without one.

> As a result, my manager is unwilling to allow me to take leave to attend court to testify.

Frankly I think the option you want here is to get a new job.

Why would you want to work for people this obnoxious?

IANAL, but I think you need *real* legal advice from an expert, not from an Internet Q&A from people who simply do not have all the legal facts or know your contract.  Note that it's possible you yourself may be in trouble with the court if you have been subpoenaed as a witness.  You really need solid legal advice, not opinions.

But regardless, when the dust settles, get a new job ASAP.  That manager and company are scum.  That's my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is to take these few days as paid leave planned in advance.

If your contract has no such provision, and your boss/manager does not consent to unpaid leave, and you are not legally required to testify (see @Joe Strazzere's answer), then this will be one of life's difficult choices for you.  Either choice would be justifiable.

If you choose to testify anyway, I would go about it like this.  Go to your manager and explain that you have given the issue serious thought, that you acknowledge and appreciate the burden it will put on the team for you to be absent for that time, but that you place greater weight on keeping this criminal behind bars.  That you have made your decision and you hope he understands.  Would he allow you to take the time as unpaid leave?  Hopefully your manager will grudgingly consent.  But if not, your conscience will be clear.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get your boss's **freely given consent,** rather than forcing their hand by getting yourself subpoenaed, you could try to reduce what you're asking for to something minimal.

1. Assure the boss this is only a small time commitment - if they're worried you'll be out for weeks on end (as might be the case for jury duty) make sure they realise you will only be away for a day or two.
2. Make a plan to cover your absence, requiring only a bit of your boss's time. Your boss might cover your meetings with clients, but why not delegate being on call to your trusted subordinates, and get those employee evaluations done earlier?
3. Make it clear to your boss that this is important to you - if you've kept your business private and given them the impression someone else was the victim of this crime, they might be under-estimating your strength of feeling.
4. Appeal to your boss's sense of justice, their willingness to help you out as you're a good employee, their desire to be a supportive manager, or their willingness to trade banked favours - whichever you think they'll respond best to.

Now you're asking them to cover one or two meetings and approve your plan - rather than asking them to sort out a replacement for an unknown period.